# Find the occurance of a variable name with different numbers at the end, in the python code

Tags: python, pandas, loops, spyder

I'm new to python. In my code I have defined a set of variables as "SpecFiles_1" to Specfiles_10" to store the binary file names. The datatype of "SpecFiles_x" is "pandas.core.series.Series" with each of them having different number of elements. i.e; for example, "SpecFiles_1" have 10 objects in it.

I want to run a loop which would take these SpecFiles_x and would run till the number of elements in it and then goes to Specfiles_(x+1) and repeat the process till the number of occurence of SpecFiles_x.

`FileId_1[0] = open(SpecFiles_1[0],'rb')`

inside the loop I want to read each of the binary files and assign them to a variable like this. I'm using spyder for coding.

Comment: This is a job for a list, not for numbered variables.

Comment: When you start appending numbers to the end of your variable names, you should almost always use a suitable data structure instead.

Comment: If you have no other way than to use numbered variables, you can use `globals()[f'SpecFiles_{x}']` to access those variables where `x` is the number which you want to access, e.g. using `for x in range(1, 11)`. However, I would _strongly_ recommend refactoring your code to a list.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `eval` function to access dynamic variable names. Like `eval('SpecFiles_{your_variable_number}')`

Sample code:

```
SpecFiles_1 = 'Something1'
SpecFiles_2 = 'Something2'
SpecFiles_3 = 'Something3'
SpecFiles_4 = 'Something4'
SpecFiles_5 = 'Something5'
SpecFiles_6 = 'Something6'
SpecFiles_7 = 'Something7'
SpecFiles_8 = 'Something8'
SpecFiles_9 = 'Something9'
SpecFiles_10 = 'Something10'
SpecFiles_11 = 'Something11'

for x in range(1, 12):
    print(eval(f'SpecFiles_{x}'))
```

Output:

```
Something1
Something2
Something3
Something4
Something5
Something6
Something7
Something8
Something9
Something10
Something11
```

In the above code, I simply printed the values of each variable, you can use your own functions or operations there which you want to perform.